# Directive not binding to property/scope set in link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am having some kind of issue binding to (or possibly just updating) a value that I set up in my directive's link function

[Here is an example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LVjfgQU33LgYIllN5Nws?p=preview)

I have my directive HTML set up like this:

```
<div id="display-area">
    <span>CHECK : {{showHighlight}}</span>
    <div id="highlight" ng-show="showHighlight"></div>
</div>
```

And its JS like this:

```
.directive("displayArea", function(){
  return {
        restrict : "E",
        replace : true,
        templateUrl : "DisplayArea.html",
        link : function(scope, el, attr){
            scope.showHighlight = false;

            el.bind("mousedown", function(e){
                scope.showHighlight = true;
            });

            el.bind("mouseup", function(e){
                scope.showHighlight = false;
            });
       }
    }
});
```

My question is, why does the binding and the `ng-show`in the HTML pick up the value of `showHighlight` initially but does not then update when the mouse events fire?
If you change the initial value of `scope.showHighlight` on line 11 of the JS then the display updates but not when you then click after that.

I'm still in wide-eyed-child mode when it comes to Angular so if I'm being daft then please slap me and give me a shove in the right direction :)

Thanks all. I appreciate the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event handlers are outside the Angular world, so it does not know that the scope value has changed. You need to call `scope.$apply();` after updating the scope variables.

```
el.bind("mousedown", function (e) {
    scope.showHighlight = true;
    scope.$apply();
 });

 el.bind("mouseup", function (e) {
    scope.showHighlight = false;
    scope.$apply();
 });
```

Comment: Boom! Works a treat, thank you very much. 8 minutes from asking a question to getting a spot on answer. Can't argue with that :)